# Center label vertically in table

Tags: css, positioning

I'm trying to create a layout with 4 small images and a label centered vertically, the label could have multiple lines.  The label sits on top of and obscures the images.  The label will be dynamically toggled.

[image]

I have done this with divs or tables but run into the same problem. Here is my table version as close as I can get:

```
p.label
{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:50%;
    margin:0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}  

table.groupbox
{
    position:relative;
}

<table class="groupbox" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr>
<td><p class="label">two line<br>label</p>
    <img src="A.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
<td><img src="B.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="C.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
<td><img src="D.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This correctly has the label spanning the full table, but it puts the bottom edge of the label at the vertical center. If I change the label's margin to something like this:

```
margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
```

I can hand center the label, but it won't work for different size labels.

### Two Answers

The answers by Nathan Manousos and Rob W both seem to work well.

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7?

Comment: IE7 support would be ideal, but something less broad would at least be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on the updated diagram, here is a solution that requires knowing the height of the whole box.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/raySU/

CSS:

```
  *{margin:0;padding:0;}
  #wrap{width:200px; height:200px; position:relative;}
  #wrap #images{position:absolute;}
  #wrap #images img{float:left;}
  #wrap #label{position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px;}
  #wrap #label table{width:100%; height:100%;}
  #wrap #label p{background-color:#eee;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="images">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div id="label">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="center">
          <p>This is my label here isnt it great yes it is</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: My diagram was unclear!  Your solution is exactly right if the label was meant to sit in between the images.  But I added a new diagram which shows the label is meant to sit on top of the images.  I wonder if td/colspan can still be used, if it can be given a 0 height yet have the text extend outside the cell?

Comment: Wow thanks that's amazing, a whole table for the one label! Works great in chrome/safari/firefox/IE8.

Comment: Any reason for/against replace the table here with some display:table/display:table-cell divs?  It works as-is to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code will produce a square with a 160x160 size. You can adjust the width and height to your wishes.

CSS:

```
.groupbox, .groupbox .label-container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
.groupbox {
  position: relative;
}
.groupbox .label-container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
}
.groupbox .A, .groupbox .B, .groupbox .C, .groupbox .D{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.groupbox .A{background-image:url("A.jpg");top:0;left:0;}
.groupbox .B{background-image:url("B.jpg");top:0;right:0;}
.groupbox .C{background-image:url("C.jpg");bottom:0;left:0;}
.groupbox .D{background-image:url("D.jpg");bottom:0;right:0;}

.groupbox .label {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="groupbox">
  <div class="A"></div><div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div><div class="D"></div>
  <div class="label-container">
    <div class="label">Any text<br />With multiple lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Final edit

Keep in mind that background should be a *background*. The text should not become unreadable because of the background. To accomplish this, you can create a 1x1 transparent image:

```
.groupbox .label-container {
    background:url("transparent.png") repeat transparent;
}
```

You can also use `background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.2)` where 0.2 is the transparency level (0=invisible, 1=fully visible). This CSS attrbute is available for FF 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera 10+ and IE 9+.

Comment: Thanks this looks really clean, but I tried it with Chrome 13 Windows and the images were repeated all over the page!  Adding "position: relative" to ".groupbox" fixed this, but I'm not sure if that's the right fix.  After that the text is not visible at all, although in the debugger I can see it's there.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Added "position:relative" to the .groupbox (absolute elements are positioned according to the nearest parent with a relative position) and "background-repeat:none" to the images. That should produce the desired results.

Comment: That helps.  Also I see a typo needs "." in front of "label" in CSS.  But even with that the text label is not visible, but in the debugger I can see it is properly centered "behind" the images.

Comment: I have tested the code with real images, and I cannot reproduce your statement. Can you copy my latest revision (CSS+HTML) and test again? I have copied the source of my successfully tested file, insread of manually typing it again.

Comment: You can see the text is centered properly but then it gets drawn over by the images in every browser I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/KLhS7/

Comment: I have added `position:absolute` to `.groupbox .label-container`. The text becomes visible to me. Also read the paragraph under the heading "Final edit" - Your issue should be solved.

Comment: Adding position:absolute does bring the text to the front.  This looks like it works correctly under chrome/safari/firefox/ie8.  Great!

Comment: This answer works well.  I accepted the other one only because it was finalized first.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a container around your table, you should be able to do this pretty easily.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="groupbox" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="label">two line<br>label</p>
        <img src="A.jpg" height=80 width=80>
      </td>
      <td><img src="B.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="C.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
      <td><img src="D.jpg" height=80 width=80></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="label">Your text here</p>
</div>

.container { 
  position: relative;
  float: left; }
.label { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 18px; /* fixed height */
  margin: -9px 0 0; }
```

Comment: Seems promising but the label is completely outside the table for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9EKjw/